# Isn't the name of an array is the address of its first element? why this code gives two different addresses?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, array-address

The code:

```cpp
    antarctica_years_end s01, s02, s03;
    s01.year = 1998;

    antarctica_years_end* pa = &s02;
    pa->year = 1999;

    antarctica_years_end trio[3]; // array of 3 structures
    trio[0].year = 2003;

    antarctica_years_end* arp[3] = { &s01, &s02, &s03 };
    

    std::cout << arp << " " << &s01 << std::endl;
```

the line:

```cpp
std::cout << arp << " " << &s01 << std::endl;
```

outputs:

```
0000007AFB0FFC68 0000007AFB0FFBB4
```

shouldn't arp and &s01 be the same? From what I've learnt so far I know that the name of an array is the address of its first element. arp is the array name of an array of pointers and &s01 is the address of its first element.

I tried changing the line to:

```cpp
std::cout << arp[0] << " " << &s01 << std::endl;
```

and it prints out the same address.

```
0000008517DBF8E4 0000008517DBF8E4
```

I am sorry if this question is stupid, I have just started learning C++ programatically and is still kind of new to this language.

Comment: 0000007AFB0FFC68 is the address of the first element in `arp`, yes. `arp` in turn is an array of pointers, the first of which is 0000008517DBF8E4.

Comment: `s01` is not an array element. Same as `n` is not: `int n = 0; int a[1]{n}; std::cout << a << ' ' <<&n << "\n";`

Comment: 0000007AFB0FFC68 is the address of the first element in arp, and the first element of arp is &s01, so 0000007AFB0FFC68  is kind of like the address of &s01?  But isn't &s01 already an address?

Comment: You might want to watch `arp` or `&arp`  and `&arp[0]`.

Comment: `&s01` is the address of `s1`, it's not the first array element address. You put this address into the array. The array element contains that address. That address is not the address of the element.

Comment: I think I get it now, thanks everyone! So basically 0000007AFB0FFC68 is the first element of the array of pointer, however that is where the computer stores the address of another address (0000008517DBF8E4).

Comment: Address of first element and value of first element are different things. Even if the value is also (another) address.

Comment: The name of an array IS NOT the address of its first elements.  The name of an array *is implicitly converted to* the address of its first element (the conversion has names such as "array to pointer conversion") but this only happens in specific contexts. In any event, the address of something is generally not equal to its value, and also has different type [although your code is obscuring that by converting both pointers to `void *` to print).  In your code `arp[0]` has *value* `&s01` but `&arp[0]` (of type `antarctica_years_end **`) has both different type and different value from `&s01`

Answer (score 1):

`arp` is an array of `3` pointers of type `antarctica_years_end`. That means, the value stored in this array are the pointers pointing to `antarctica_years_end` type.

In memory view of `arp` would be something like this:

```
     arp              s01 [address 100]
         +-----+       +-----+
  arp[0] | 100 |------>|     |     s02 [address 200]
         +-----+       +-----+       +-----+
  arp[1] | 200 |-------------------> |     |         s03 [address 300]
         +-----+                     +-----+          +-----+
  arp[2] | 300 |------------------------------------->|     | 
         +-----+                                      +-----+
```

From this, it should be clear that `arp[0]` and `&s01` are same because address of `s01` is value of first member of array `arp` i.e. `arp[0]`.

For built-in subscript operator, the language standard states that - `The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2)), ...`

By this definition, `arp[0]` can be written as `*((arp) + (0))`.

Similarly, for `arp`:

```
arp -> &(*(arp)) -> &(*((arp) + (0))) -> &(arp[0]) -> &arp[0]
                       \          /
                        +--------+
                             |
                           arp[0]
```

That means `arp` is address of it's first element i.e. `&arp[0]` and hence `arp` and `&s01`, when print, give different output.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you

```
s1:           [1998]
              ↑
              &s1 = 0000007AFB0FFBB4
              |
arp[0] = &s1: |
              ↓
arp: [0000007AFB0FFBB4][...]
     ↑    
     &arp = &arp[0] = 0000007AFB0FFC68
```

Comment: Thank you, this graph of yours really helped me out!